# Sound not work on android game build in unity 5

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game and the sound works fine when I play it in the unity editor or through the "build and run" option for android.

However when I use the apk file and install the game on the phone the sound does not seem to be working.

Can someone please give me a reference for resolving sound issues on android when developing through Unity 5? My work is done on Windows 10.

Script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour{

bool check = false; 
AudioSource sounds;
public AudioClip coin;
public AudioClip treasure;
public AudioClip power;
public AudioClip g_power;
public AudioClip spring_up;
public AudioClip cheerUp;

void Start ()
{
    sounds = GetComponent<AudioSource> (); 
}

void Update ()
{ 
    if (!check && Movement.gameStart) {
        check = true;
    }   

} 

void OnCollisionStay2D (Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "box" && GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y <= 0)  
        Movement.inAir = false;    
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
    if (UI.sfx) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "coin") 
            sounds.PlayOneShot (coin, 1f);
        else if (col.gameObject.tag == "treasure") {
            sounds.PlayOneShot (treasure, 1f); 
            sounds.PlayOneShot (cheerUp, 1f); 
        } 
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y <= 0) {
            if (col.gameObject.tag == "green") {
                sounds.PlayOneShot (g_power, 1f);
                sounds.PlayOneShot (spring_up, 1f);
            } else if (col.gameObject.tag == "blue") {
                sounds.PlayOneShot (power, 1f);
                sounds.PlayOneShot (spring_up, 1f);
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: make sure your AudioSource in the unity editor is set to full volume and set your android to full volume also , If it doesnt help , post some code .

Comment: @LumbusterTick every thing works fine when I build and run from unity but when I install same apk file then sound are not working...

Comment: What is the codec of your audio source , maybe your android doesnt support it .Download free open source software audacity and change its codec and try again .

Comment: I just noticed you are playing one shot audio clips one after another from one audio source , that makes problem most of the time ,play only one and check again please.

Comment: @LumbusterTick my android support format when I play game via build and run so I don't think there is problem with format..I am using mp3 and ogg

Comment: I checked split application binary in Player setting ..this solved my issue